# I'd like to ask you a question about FineScript's ATR strategy trading

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

1. Stop loss

- Find the closing value of the lower portion of the ATR Bands when entering the strategy
  Exit or close when reaching or breaking the value (fixed the lower value up to exit or close)

2. TP

- Find the closing value of the upper part of ATR Bands when entering the strategy
  TP when the value is reached or broken (fixed up to TP when found)

```
//@version=5
strategy('JKHK', shorttitle='JKHK', overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, initial_capital=100000, default_qty_value=100, commission_value=0.075, slippage=3)

// Inputs
atrPeriod = input.int(title='ATR Period', defval=14, minval=1)
srcUpper = input(title='Source Upper', defval=close)
srcLower = input(title='Source Lower', defval=close)
atrMultiplierUpper = input(title='ATR Multiplier Upper', defval=2)
atrMultiplierLower = input(title='ATR Multiplier Lower', defval=2)

// ATR
atr = ta.atr(atrPeriod)

// Plotting
//plot(srcUpper + atr * atrMultiplierUpper, color=color.new(color.green, 0))
//plot(srcLower - atr * atrMultiplierLower, color=color.new(color.red, 0))


// ema200
ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)

plot(ema200, title='ema200', color=color.new(color.white, 0), linewidth=2)


longema200 = (close>ema200)


lower_band_value = srcLower - (atr * atrMultiplierLower)

upper_band_value = srcUpper + (atr * atrMultiplierUpper)


var float atr_upper_band = na
var float atr_lower_band = na

longCondition = longema200

atr_upper_band  := longCondition ? upper_band_value : atr_upper_band  
atr_lower_band  := longCondition ? lower_band_value : atr_lower_band 

plot(atr_upper_band, title='atr_upper_band', color=color.new(color.white, 0), linewidth=2)
plot(atr_lower_band, title='atr_lower_band', color=color.new(color.white, 0), linewidth=2)

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = longCondition )
strategy.exit("LongTP", "Long", stop = atr_upper_band )
strategy.exit("LongSP", "Long", stop = atr_lower_band )
```

Comment: Where is the question that the title says you want to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mainly correct but it needs a few tweaks.

I believe, you want to enter a position when the price crosses above the EMA. If that is the case, you can do:

```
longema200 = ta.crossover(close, ema200)
```

Because if you do `longema200 = (close > ema200)`, your ATR lower and upper bands (the ones you are using for the TP and SL) will be updated every time the price is above the EMA line.

`ta.crossover()` will only return `true` once the price crosses the EMA line. Therefore, it will prevent updating your TP and SL frequently.

The second change you need is, you should combine your `strategy.exit()` and use the `stop` argument for SL and `limit` argument for TP. You can use the `comment_loss` and `comment_profit` arguments to specify a specific comment for SL and TP respectively.

```
longema200 = ta.crossover(close, ema200)

strategy.exit("LongExit", "Long", stop = atr_lower_band, limit = atr_upper_band, comment_loss = "Long-SL", comment_profit = "Long-TP")
```